# Problem with getting values in a row instead of a column from .json file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have several .json files that I would like to combine into one .csv file. The .json files look like this:

```json
{"version":1.3,"people":[{"person_id":[-1],"pose_keypoints_2d":[346.096,136.31,0.822246,339.237,210.457,0.840786,264.747,203.769,0.807762,149.518,183.631,0.854263,88.6763,82.0749,0.906274,400.122,210.38,0.854152,508.225,183.228,0.898651,555.846,75.2072,0.958429,345.636,345.892,0.111406,291.626,346.153,0.194191,0,0,0,0,0,0,393.258,346.08,0.15249,0,0,0,0,0,0,339.241,136.084,0.804675,352.463,136.006,0.702916,305.539,156.42,0.639209,359.362,156.248,0.325405,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
"face_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_2d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_2d":[],"pose_keypoints_3d":[],
"face_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_left_keypoints_3d":[],"hand_right_keypoints_3d":[]}]}
```

The code I use to load and combine files:

```py
import json
import os
import pandas as pd

data = []

for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/ciach/PycharmProjects/CSV/"):
    if file.endswith(".json"):
        data2 = json.load(open(os.path.join("C:/Users/ciach/PycharmProjects/CSV/", file)))
        df = pd.json_normalize(data2,record_path=['people','pose_keypoints_2d'])
        data.append(df)

temp = pd.concat(data, ignore_index = True) 
temp.to_csv("keypoints.csv", index=False)
```

After compilation with two files, I get the following results in .csv file (all values are in one column):

```
338.938
156.226
...
0.000000
0.000000
```

I would like to get the values only from the list `'pose_keypoints_2d'` in one row for each .json file instead of one whole column from all files. Something like that:

```
338.938000 156.226000 0.322833 ...  0.000000  0.000000
346.096000 136.310000 0.822246 ...  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: What is the result of `print(data)`?

Comment: I think it is trivial to solve, but I cannot show you because shown input and output looks unrelated. Where is the sequence `338.938000  156.226000 0.322833 ...  0.000000  0.000000`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You df is a column of 75 rows when it's added to data2.

Try replacing this:

```
data.append(df)
```

by this

```
data.append(df.T)
```

Which (df.T) is one row with 75 columns

Comment: It wokrs! Thank you very much

Comment: Great, please accept answer so that it will leave the queue of 'unanswered' questions. Cheers